# Как отменить запрет перехода по ссылке

Tags: javascript

У меня на странице много ссылок, практически всё грузиться в фоне и я отменил действие браузера по умолчанию, то есть отменил переходи по ним, но вот проблема, на странице имееться главная иконка клик по которому должен обновить страницу, как именно ему отменить отмену перехода? (Я надеюсь вы поняли), код который я использовал для отмени перехода:

```js
jQuery('a').on('click', function (e) {
   //Отменяю переход
   e.preventDefault(); 
   //Получаю ссылку
   var link = this.getAttribute('href');
   // Использую ссылку
   $( '#contentPage' ).load(link + ' #content', function( response, status, xhr ){
    // И здесь куча не нужного сейчас кода
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверняка у ссылки вашей главной иконки имеется какой-нибудь уникальный *class* (если нет, то следует его добавить). Далее чуть правим селектор и назначаем обработчик всем ссылкам, у которых такого класса [нет](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8%D0%B7_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2).

```js
jQuery('a:not(.normal)').on('click', function(e) {
  //Отменяю переход
  e.preventDefault();
  //Получаю ссылку
  var link = this.getAttribute('href');
  // Видим, что обработчик срабатывает на всех ссылках, 
  // кроме той у которой есть класс ".normal"
  console.log(link);
  // Использую ссылку
  /*
  $('#contentPage').load(link + ' #content', function(response, status, xhr) {
      // И здесь куча не нужного сейчас кода
    }
  });
  */
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="normal" href="#F5">Обновить</a>
<br><br>
<a class="" href="#first">Первая ссылка</a>
<br>.<br>.<br>.<br>
<a class="" href="#Last">Последняя ссылка</a>
```